# Using mvel/ListCreator in Java to export report

Tags: java

I want to export report in java using ListCreator. After few hours looking up information, I found its source code at this link: https://github.com/mvel/mvel/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mvel2/optimizers/impl/refl/collection/ListCreator.java

But looking up for its documentation, tutorial, example doesn't give any result. Is there anyone here knows how to use it?. Could you give me some example, tutorial link or document about it.

Thanks for your help.